# Dynamically querying a table with a variable name yields a vague "Incorrect syntax near 'Select'" Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to query the top 5 rows in an existing table with a dynamically generated name. I understand that many on SO have had problems/questions doing something similar, and I've read through a handful of solutions, but all to no avail.

I can generate the table name just fine; the issue is then taking the table name and using it in another script, namely something like `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM (table name here).`

Here is what I have now:

```
DECLARE @oldtablename VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @oldtablequery VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @oldtablename = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%tablekeywords_test%'' 
AND CONVERT(varchar(8), RIGHT(TABLE_NAME, 8), 112) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)'
exec(@oldtablename)

-- up until here, everything works fine. The following does not:
--EXEC('select top 5 * from databasename.dbo.'+@oldtablename+'')
SET @oldtablequery = 'SELECT TOP 5 * FROM databasename.dbo.'+@oldtablename+';'
exec(@oldtablequery)
```

The error I get with both the `exec( )` attempt (the one in comments) and the `Set...exec` attempt is:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea which `'SELECT'` error the compiler refers to. I'm going to guess this isn't a syntax error, but perhaps a logical one (i.e., there's something fundamental I am or am not doing rather than omitting a comma or something), but I'm not entirely certain, as I am new to dynamic SQL.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:** I'm not struggling to generate or print the desired table name. I am trying to use the table name in a new query to select the 5 top rows of that specific table, `@oldtablename.`

Comment: First  `PRINT @oldtablename` and `PRINT @oldtablequery` then post it here to debug.

Comment: Anyway it looks like classic **[SELECT * FROM sales + @yymm](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm)**

Comment: Looks like you are thinking that after the first EXEC, that `@oldtablename` is going to be populated with the name of a table.   It isn't.  Look at it again, closely.

Comment: Everyone, please see my edit for clarification at the bottom of the OP. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eli's answer points out the problem.   There was no need to use dynamic SQL in the first query.   This would solve the problem:

```
DECLARE @oldtablename VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @oldtablequery VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @oldtablename = (
     SELECT 
         TOP 1 TABLE_NAME 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tablekeywords_test%' 
     AND CONVERT(varchar(8), RIGHT(TABLE_NAME, 8), 112) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112));


-- up until here, everything works fine. The following does not:
--EXEC('select top 5 * from databasename.dbo.'+@oldtablename+'')
SET @oldtablequery = 'SELECT TOP 5 * FROM databasename.dbo.'+@oldtablename+';'
exec(@oldtablequery)
```

Comment: Actually, this does not solve the problem; the console underlines the `select` right after `SET @oldtablename` and warns about incorrect `'SELECT'` syntax.

Comment: @daOnlyBG I updated Tab's answer to work fine. The query nested after  SET needed to be contained within parenthesis.

Comment: @Eli the updates didn't show yet, but I now understand the correct adjustment and the script works just fine. Thank you to you and Tab.

Answer (score 3):

Your first query is returning a query, i.e. a select statement.
Your second query is trying to select the top 5...from the select statement... which doesn't make sense.

Please look at the following - it is your query, with the change of printing out the query instead of executing it. Look at that query which it prints out, and the issue should be self-explanatory.

```
DECLARE @oldtablename VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @oldtablequery VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @oldtablename = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%tablekeywords_test%'' 
AND CONVERT(varchar(8), RIGHT(TABLE_NAME, 8), 112) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)'
exec(@oldtablename)

-- up until here, everything works fine. The following does not:
--EXEC('select top 5 * from databasename.dbo.'+@oldtablename+'')
SET @oldtablequery = 'SELECT TOP 5 * FROM databasename.dbo.'+@oldtablename+';'
print @oldtablequery
```

If you would like to preserve just the table name from the first query, you'll need to use a second variable to capture that.

Comment: Good analysis, bad suggestion.   The solution to the problem is not to use dynamic SQL in the first query.   There's no need for it.

Comment: @Eli, I am unsure whether I've explained the problem properly. I want SQL Server to run the query `Select Top 5 * From databasename.dbo.(desired table here)`, not print the name of the table. I can have the table name printed simply by running everything up until my comments in the code sample above.

Comment: @TabAlleman Agreed that Dynamic SQL wasn't the appropriate medium here. The only piece which I was pointing out was that the second query _cannot_ work as it is a full SQL Statement instead of a table name. I now see your answer which fixed that as well. The point I was addressing is the "vague error message" in the title of this question

Comment: @daOnlyBG you weren't getting a table name by running the code up until the comment, you were getting a full query. The answer by Tab Alleman will do that for you. I was merely pointing out the source of the error, and how to go about circumventing it

Comment: @Eli Thanks, I now understand that I was only getting a query result instead of the object's name. I will await TabAlleman's response to my comment though, because his suggested answer also produces a similar error response.

Comment: @daOnlyBG see my comment on Tab's answer

Comment: @Eli understood, and I upvoted for the explanation, but your last sentence leaves out a lot.   Like if he nested a second variable in his first dynamic query, then he would have to make the whole thing one big dynamic query, or the second variable wouldn't exist in the context of the second dynamic query.   I didn't want OP to start down that road.   :)